# Google Maps SDK won't open pin

Tags: ios, google-maps-sdk-ios

I have a google maps view inside my app showing a pin.

```
func setUpGoogleMapView() {

    let camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: self.site.latitude, longitude: self.site.longitude, zoom: 15.0)
    let mapView = GMSMapView.map(withFrame: CGRect.zero, camera: camera)
    mapView.frame = googleMapView.frame
    self.view.addSubview(mapView)

    let marker = GMSMarker()
    marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: self.site.latitude, longitude: self.site.longitude)
    marker.title = self.site.name
    marker.map = mapView
}
```

If I manually call `UIApplication.shared.openURL` passing in a URL with the query, it opens in a different mode (the annotation doesn't show the name of the place, shows latitude & longitude instead) or doesn't open if the user hasn't installed google maps.

```
@IBAction func directionsButtonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
    if (UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(URL(string:"comgooglemaps://")!)) {

        UIApplication.shared.openURL(URL(string:
            "comgooglemaps://?center=\(self.site.latitude),\(self.site.longitude)&zoom=14&views=traffic&q=\(self.site.latitude),\(self.site.longitude)")!)
    } else {
        print("Can't use comgooglemaps://");
    }
}
```

How can I open google maps in safari using `UIApplication.shared.openURL`?

How should I have google maps to display the pin with name of the place if I call `UIApplication.shared.openURL`?

I would like to have the same directions mode after using `UIApplication.shared.openURL`.

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FXdG5.png)

Comment: Can you post the screenshot of the desired output you are looking for?

Comment: Thanks. It wouldn't let me to add an image so I added a link

Comment: The screenshot you have shown is the output you are looking for?

Comment: Yes it is the output I'm looking for

Comment: Do you have the lat,long of the place you want to show at google map?

Comment: From place name

Comment: You said "_you have google maps view inside my app showing a pin_", so what is that google maps view and what code are you using to show pin? Please post code for that.

Comment: @Hooda - i added the relevant code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Swift 3.x:**

```
let strPlaceName = "batumi+botanical+garden" as String!
let url = URL(string: "https://www.google.com/maps?q="+strPlaceName!)

if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url!) {
    if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
        UIApplication.shared.open(url!, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
    } else {
        // for iOS 10, below is deprecated
        UIApplication.shared.openURL(url!)
    }
}
```

**Objective-C:**

```
NSString *strPlaceName = @"Batumi+Botanical+Garden";
NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://www.google.com/maps/place/%@",strPlaceName];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:str];

if([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:url]) {      
    if([[UIDevice currentDevice].systemVersion floatValue] >= 10.0){
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url options:@{} completionHandler:nil];
    } else {
        // for iOS 10, below is deprecated
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! That works really well! I cant upvote it though, it says I dont have enough reputation yet :) @Hooda

Comment: @NatukaKh Glad to know that it worked! You need 15 reputation to upvote. If you wish, you can upvote later when you have enough reputation.

Comment: Will do :) Thanks again!